# Regex matching either positive/negative floats, ints or string

Tags: regex, negative-number

I want to be able to match and parse some parameters read from a file such as :

"type:int,register_id:15,value:123456"
"type:int,register_id:16,value:-456789"
"type:double,register_id:17,value:123.456"
"type:double,register_id:18,value:-456.789"
"type:bool,register_id:19,value:true"
"type:bool,register_id:20,value:false"
"type:string,register_id:17,value:Test Set Data Register"

I've come up with the following Regex expression :

(^(type:)\b(bool|int|double|string)\b,(\bregister_id:\b)([1-9][0-9]*),(\bvalue:\b)(.*)$)

but I have issues where there are negative floats or ints, I can't get the hyphen sorted properly ...

Can someone point me in the right direction ?

https://regex101.com/r/WhXmBE/3

Thanks !

Tried [\s\S] but it reads everything, tried -? as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example, this seems to work:

```
(^(type:)(bool|int|double|string),(register_id:)([1-9][0-9]*),(value:)(.*)$)
```

At least from the example, I didn't see why the \b are necessary. Apologies if I missed something.

Looking at what you try to achieve, I would actually consider moving away from regexes, as regexes by themselves add complexity. You will likely have an easier life if you approach it like this:

1. Split the line by "," to get the key value pairs
2. Split each key value pair by the first ":" to split key and value
3. Validate that all keys are present and that every value matches the format for the key (e.g. if the type is bool then the value should parse to a bool)

You can easily adjust every step to e.g. trim whitespaces.

Edit: Fixed typo

Comment: Hello Christian, thank you for your reply ! It works perfectly !